# 405 http status code clarification for delete rest api in spring mvc

Tags: json, rest, http, spring-mvc, http-status-codes

I have a rest api for delete as RequestMethod.DELETE.

I have the @PathVariable("mediaId") String mediaId.

When I invoke the api with out a path paramert value as below, I get 405 Method Not Allowed.

http://localhost:8080/myservice/deleteme/mediaId/

The definition of 405 in wiki as below,

> 405 Method Not Allowed A request method is not supported for the
>   requested resource; for example, a GET request on a form which
>   requires data to be presented via POST, or a PUT request on a
>   read-only resource.

Since i use the correct http method DELETE to invoke the delete api, why I am getting 405? In my opinion, 400 is more valid?

Comment: _"Since i use the correct http method DELETE to invoke the delete api,"_  You wrote yourself that you don't invoke the "delete api": _"When I invoke the api with out a path paramer value as below"_  = not the "delete api"

Comment: @zeroflagL Shouldnt the missiong path parameter falls under with 400 Bad Request? What i meant was if i invoke this DELETE method with as POST method via postman, i can expect 405 according to the explanation.

Comment: The path parameter is not missing. It's another URI alltogether.

Comment: i didnt get what you mean. the path parameter is there with emplty value